# Joint pdf of two random processes

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability

Let $y[n]$ be a random process which is defined as follows:
\begin{equation}
y[n] = x[n] - x[n-1]
\end{equation}
where $x[n]$ is iid and takes the values of $\{1,0\}$ with probability $p$ and $1-p$, respectively. I want to find the joint pdf of $y[n]$ and $x[n]$.
\begin{equation}
f_{y[n],x[n]}(y_n,x_n) = f_{y[n]|x[n]}(y_n|x_n)f_{x[n]}(x_n)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
f_{x[n]}(x_n) = p \delta(x_n - 1) + (1-p) \delta(x_n) 
\end{equation}

I need to find $f_{y[n]|x[n]}(y_n|x_n)$ to proceed. How do I find the conditional pdf?

Edit: If I further want to find $f_{y[n_1],y[n_2]}(y_1,y_2)$ then:

Case $1$: $|n_2 - n_1| = 1$

$f_{y[n_1],y[n_2]}(y_1,y_2)$ = $f_{y[n_2]|y[n_1]}(y_2|y_1)$$f_{y[n_1]}(y_1)$

$y[n_2] = x[n_2] - x[n_2 -1] = x[n_2] - x[n_1] = x[n_2] - (y[n_1] - x[n_1 - 1])$

Since $y[n_1]$ is given, there are two random quantities and the conditional pdf is $p^2\delta(y_2 - (2-y_1)) + (1-p)^2\delta(y_2 + y_1) + 2p(1-p)\delta(y_2 - (1-y_1))$. Is this approach correct?

Comment: Complicated notation and imho complicated approach. It is easy to see that $(x_n,y_n)$ take values in
$\Big\{(0,-1),\,(0,0),\,(0,1),\,(1,-1),\,(1,0),\,(1,1)\Big\}$ with probabilities
$(1-p)p,\,(1-p)(1-p),\,0,\,0,\,p^2,\,p(1-p)\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. what about the second order pdf of $y[n]$, meaning that $f_{y[n_1],y[n_2]}(y_1,y_2)$?

Comment: What is that ? $\phantom{crab}$

Comment: You sample $y[n]$ in $n_1$ and $n_2$ time instants and find the the joint pdf.

Comment: Hint: for $n_2-n_1\ge 2$ the random variables $y_{n_2}$ and $y_{n_1}$ are independent. The case $n_2=n_1+1$ should be doable in a similar way than $(x_n,y_n)$. You will learn more when you try this yourself.

Comment: @KurtG. Actually I was looking for $|n_1 - n_2| = 1$ case. The other case is trivial.

Comment: @KurtG. I made an edit for the conditional pdf. Can you check that?

Comment: Same complicated approach as before. I do not see the problem of finding the joint pdf of $y_n$ and $y_{n+1}$ solved. Hint: $y_n$ takes values in $\{-1,0,+1\}$ and so does $y_{n+1}\,.$ This leads to $9$ various tuples for $(y_n,y_{n+1})\,.$ Figure out which values the independent $x_{n+1},x_n,x_{n-1}$ must take in each case and calculate their probabilites.